# BIRT rptdesign not recognising class added as .jar

Tags: java, jar, resources, reporting, birt

My BIRT rptdesign has a .jar file added of a class named MyFirstClass.
I need to access data from the .jar. But I'm getting error while accessing the class in the script of the rptdesign.

Error : **ReferenceError: "MyFirstClass" is not defined**

I have the .jar present in the Report Project , then added the .jar to classpath of the Report Project, and then added the .jar to the Resources of the rptdesign.

The code snippet for importing the class from jar file in the script of rptdesign :

```
    importPackage(Packages.com.demo);
    var obj = new MyFirstClass();
    myData= obj.dataFromClass();
```

Comment: Are you using separate BIRT report project?

Comment: yes. it is a separate BIRT report Project. I have another project where I have the java class. I have exported this java class as jar and the added that jar to the report project.

Comment: ohh...I posted answer first and then saw your comment.I will soon edit my answer.

Comment: @NGB Did you ever resolved this?. Even I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If your xxx.rptdesign is in the same project where your java class is then,
try following in BIRT script,

```
controller = new Packages.com.demo.MyFirstClass();
myData=controller.dataFromClass();
```

Comment: where is your rptdesign? in the same project or you are using different project?

Comment: say Project_1 is a report project and it contains the rptdesign.
Project_2 is a java project that contains the java class.
I have exported this java class as a jar and then added it to the rptdesign in Project_1

Comment: that I uderstood...but I have done this in one single project....and its running... For your scenario I have to try first.....then and then I can help you...When I get time ...I will back and help you soon...

Comment: Sure. Please respond when you try. Thanks !